# E quando o overflow não funciona?

Tags: css, imagem

Estou trabalhando com algumas imagens com um efeito de zoom usando  `transform: scale(x);`. Porém quando dá o zoom, principalmente no mobile, a imagem ultrapassa o container lateral.

Assim ela não aparece em si mas o tamanho dela ultrapassa gerando aquele vácuo lateral que possibilita puxar a tela para o lado e fica um espaço em branco do lado, e o `overflow: hidden;` não está resolvendo.

Alguém sabe outra maneira de esconder isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.hoverzoom:hover > img {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Você ta desabilitando o zoom com `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">` ?

Comment: creio que não, é necessário ai no caso desabilitaria o efeito de zoom no mobile?

Comment: olha o que ta aparecendo no meu console, mas isso ja aparecia antes do efeito de zoom eu acho... The key "width:device-width" is not recognized and ignored.

Comment: fiz isso amigo funcionou.. .mt obg

Comment: O `overflow: hidden` não pode ficar na <img>, deve ficar em alguma <div> pai dela;

Answer (score 0):

Mas você precisa colocar um hover no mobile e tablet? Existem várias formas de resolver isso, uma delas é desabilitar esse scale em resoluções menores:

```
@media screen and (max-width:990px) {
  .hoverzoom:hover > img {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```